# Ping is not working on single topology created on mininet

Tags: mininet

I am new to Mininet and ODL,so please do guide me
When I create a simple topology using below command in mininet i.e

> > sudo mn –topo=single,2 –mac –controller=remote –switch=ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
> >     ** network topology is created
> >
> > h1 ping h2
> >     host unreachable
> >     host unreachable

using $sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 dump-flows s1 i couldn't see any flows

But this is not the case when i created tree and linear topology.Dynamic ping was working.

Please find the snapshot of error message :
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1aYl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your command to create a single topology , IP is missing

sudo mn --topo single,2 --controller=remote,ip=[controller IP] --switch ovsk

I hope this will work for you now

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the case for me many times. Mininet causes such problems quite often. For me, issues appear when deploying a topology with one ***single*** switch, which, as I can see, is also your case. If you can, avoid creating just one switch and the problem will disappear.

However, try to also specify your controller's IP like this :

```
--controller=remote,ip=[CONTROLLER_IP]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to create the flows between h1 and h2?

Try this:

```
sh ovs-ofctl del-flows s1

sh ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 in_port=1,actions=output:2
sh ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 in_port=2,actions=output:1

sh ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1

pingall
```